# Serialiaze a map[A,B] with lift-json knowing A<->String

Tags: json, scala, serialization, lift-json

I want to serialize a HashMap having type HashMap[Coord,Unite] with lift-json. those types are specific to my project but there is Coord -> String with the toString function and i can have my Coord back from String (even if it's not coded here but that's not relevant). 
So i thought i could ask lift-json to serialize a Map[String,Coord] but here serialize(format)(y) try to apply the same function (in a recursive way) when I want it to use the serialize function adapted to Map[String,Coord]. The reason i can't do the transformation outside the Serializer is because this HashMap is part of a bigger case class so i need lift-json to know how to serialize and deserialize it.

```
class UnitzSerializer extends Serializer[HashMap[Coord,Unite]] {

private val UnitzClass = classOf[HashMap[Coord,Unite]]

def deserialize(implicit format:Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo,JValue), HashMap[Coord,Unite]]= {
case (TypeInfo(UnitzClass,_), json) => json match {
  case x:JValue => (deserialize(format)((TypeInfo(classOf[Map[String,Unite]],None),x))).map(y => (Coord(0,0),y._2))
  case _  => throw new Exception("ONOz")
}
}


def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
       case x: HashMap[Coord,Unite] => {
     val y:Map[String,Unite] = x.map(z => (z._1.toString,z._2))
 serialize(format)(y)
   }
}

}
```

I could rewrite the serialization and deserialization of a Map[String,Unite] but that would be a lot of useless code just because i dont understand how lift-json works enough.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but it seems to me the issue here is type erasure; at runtime, there's no difference between `HashMap[Coord, Unite]` and `HashMap[String, Unite]`, which may explain the endless recursion.

Comment: It could, but as far as I remember you don't get one on serialization; for deserialization, you'll have to construct it from the TypeInfo on your own. Not trivial and not pretty.